# NUnit Theory with an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, theory

It is a design/pattern I am looking for.

I have a nunit test, in which I plan to use an existing enum as theory. The existing enum has almost 30 members.

Say it's like:

```
enum ABigEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}


[Theory]
public void Test(ABigEnum enumValue)
{
//generate someValue based upon enumValue    
Assert.That(someValue, Is.True, "an amazing assertion message");
}
```

But, the test should assert, value D in enum for False and all others for True.
Can we do it without using if-else conditional (as a holy doctrine I avoid conditionals in tests)?
Or is there any interesting pattern that you guys follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found this way to write the test. If someone posts a better way, shall accept it. Else, here is the answer.

```
[Theory]
public void Test(ABigEnum enumValue)
{
//generate someValue based upon enumValue    
bool truthValue = IsD(enumValue);
Assert.That(someValue, Is.EqualTo(truthValue), "an amazing assertion message");
}

IsD(ABigEnum enumValue)
{
    return (enumValue==ABigEnum.D)
}
```

Possibly not the most ideal solution and does externally introduce conditional code path to the test.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute provided by NUnit, when writing such tests. I believe these tests are referred to as Data Driven Tests.

Here is how my version of your test would look like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public enum ABigEnum
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    public IEnumerable TestValues
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(ABigEnum.A, false).SetName("Assert A");
            yield return new TestCaseData(ABigEnum.B, false).SetName("Assert B");
            yield return new TestCaseData(ABigEnum.C, false).SetName("Assert C");
            yield return new TestCaseData(ABigEnum.D, true).SetName("Assert D");
        }
    }

    [Theory]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestClass), "TestValues")]
    public void Test(ABigEnum enumValue, bool assertValue)
    {
        //generate someValue based upon enumValue    
        Assert.That(enumValue, Is.EqualTo(assertValue), "an amazing assertion message");
    }

}
```

**Edit 1**

Actually, you can use `Datapoint` attribute with `Theory`. Something like this:

```
    public enum ABigEnum
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    [Datapoint]
    public Tuple<ABigEnum, bool>[] TestValues = new[]
                       {
                           new Tuple<ABigEnum, bool>(ABigEnum.A, false), new Tuple<ABigEnum, bool>(ABigEnum.B, false),
                           new Tuple<ABigEnum, bool>(ABigEnum.C, false), new Tuple<ABigEnum, bool>(ABigEnum.D, true)
                       };

    [Theory]
    public void Test(Tuple<ABigEnum,bool> data)
    {
        //generate someValue based upon enumValue    
        Assert.That(data.Item1, Is.EqualTo(data.Item2), "an amazing assertion message");
    }
```

Comment: this is an interesting one, only issue is the enum to be used is large & long!! so will have yield around 25 times or so!

Comment: a query, why do you have both Theory & TestCaseSource attributes? Do they work together like this?

Comment: @dushyantp - you can have any implementation that can return an `IEnumerable` and use it as your TestCaseSource. You need `Theory` or `Test` to tell NUnit that this is a Test/Theory, only such decorated methods are scanned for. `TestCaseSource` tells NUnit to run the same method as many times. You can have multiple Attributes.

Comment: Thanks Shrikanth, those are real good ways of doing it. Only issue being, as stated above, the point of using a Theory is that we do not want to rewrite the whole enum again (as it is required in both testcasesource and datapoint). Your points are very helpful though. Appreciated.

Comment: Need more context to improve this. Enum seems to be a poor choices as you have data and assert value to be passed on. Try using a Dictionary instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve your requirements with this:

```
enum ABigEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

[Theory]
public void Test(ABigEnum enumValue)
{
    bool someValue = enumValue != ABigEnum.D;
    Assert.That(someValue, Is.True, "an amazing assertion message");
}
```

This will give you `false` when passing in `D` and `true` for all other values.

Because this logic is not something that can "known" by the system you will have to make some kind of decision whether it is an if / else or switch.

**However**, this "Test" looks more like a method than a pure test and you might want to re-think what it is you are testing and trying to achieve because as you highlight you don't really want a lot of logic in a test.